# ReferenceError : barChartHelper is not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, d3.js

I am getting error :

barChartHelper is not defined .

**app.js**

```
   var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    cons = require('consolidate'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    Server = require('mongodb').Server;

app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

var mongoclient = new MongoClient(new Server("localhost", 27017));
var db = mongoclient.db('mydb');

app.use( express.static( "img" ) );

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    // Find one document in our collection

    db.collection('things').find({},{'Created':1, 'MRP':1}).toArray(function(err, docs){
      console.log(docs);
      res.render('hello',{'docs':docs});


   });

});


app.get('*', function(req, res){
    db.collection('things').find({},{'Created':1, 'MRP':1}).toArray(function(err, docs){
      console.log(docs);
      res.render('index',{'docs':docs});


   });

});



mongoclient.open(function(err, mongoclient) {

    if(err) throw err;

    app.listen(9001);
    console.log('Express server started on port 9001');
});
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>D3 Server-side Demo</title>

    <style>
      body {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
      }

      .svg-chart .background {
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        stroke: #ccc;
        fill: #fdfdfd;
        stroke-width: 1px;
      }

      .svg-chart .bar { fill: #4682B4; }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>D3 Server-side Demo</h1>
  <%-
      barChartHelper.getBarChart({
        data: docs,
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        xAxisLabel: '2012',
        yAxisLabel: 'Views',
        containerId: 'bar-chart-small'
      })
    %>
    <hr>
    <%-
      barChartHelper.getBarChart({
        data: docs,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        xAxisLabel: '2012',
        yAxisLabel: 'Views',
        containerId: 'bar-chart-large'
      })
    %> 



  </body>
</html>
```

and the error come is :

> ReferenceError: /home/shubham/Music/testing/mamy/views/index.ejs:28
>   26|   
>   27|
>
> ## D3 Server-side Demo
>
> > > 28|   <%-
> > >        29|       barChartHelper.getBarChart({
> > >       30|         data: docs,
> > >       31|         width: 400,
>
> barChartHelper is not defined    at eval (eval at 
>   (/home/shubham/Music/testing/mamy/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:464:12),
>   :10:16)    at returnedFn
>   (/home/shubham/Music/testing/mamy/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:493:17) 
>   at View.exports.renderFile [as engine]
>   (/home/shubham/Music/testing/mamy/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:350:31) 
>   at View.render
>   (/home/shubham/Music/testing/mamy/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8)
>   at Function.app.render
>   (/home/shubham/Music/testing/mamy/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:561:10)
>   at ServerResponse.res.render
>   (/home/shubham/Music/testing/mamy/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:845:7)
>   at /home/shubham/Music/testing/mamy/app.js:123:11    at
>   /home/shubham/Music/testing/mamy/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:173:9
>   at
>   /home/shubham/Music/testing/mamy/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:205:48
>   at
>   /home/shubham/Music/testing/mamy/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:855:28

and i have both related file **bar_chart_helper.js , bar_charts.js**  into views folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the required, explicit `<script></script>` tags in your template that references those scripts. Non-template scripts do not get automagically inserted into your templates just by placing them in the same directory.

Comment: if i am adding a <script></script>   instead of <%-   %> then it is not showing any thing

Comment: No, you have to *add* script tags *inside* your template (e.g. inside the `<head></head>`). Like `<script src="/js/bar_charts.js"></script><script src="/js/bar_chart_helper.js"></script>`. Additionally you will have to move those two files into your public directory so that browsers can reach them.

Comment: oh Thanks i need to  add this line on server side   app.locals.barChartHelper = require('./bar_chart_helper');